# electron drag and drop remote files on desktop

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

**Objective:**

Use [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)`s [Native File Drag & Drop](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/native-file-drag-drop) to drag remote files out of electron-app into the operating system's world for example on desktop or some opened folder

**Approach:**

**renderer**

In renderer, use `ipcRenderer.send('ondragstart', url_to_download)`

**main process**

In main process , in `ipcMain.on('ondragstart'`

1. First download remote file and wait for it to complete
2. Then use `event.sender.startDrag(` and as file provide os path of downloaded file

**Code:**

1. https://github.com/mafar/electron-drag-drop-remote-files
2. Download repo and then `npm install && npm start`
3. `main.js` and `renderer.js` are files with logic

**Issues:**

1. user wants to drag a remote item and drop it on os desktop
2. user must keep left mouse pressed and not release it when dropping on os desktop untill dragicon appears
3. it is becuase of fact that dragicon takes time untill file is downloaded and availabe for drop
4. If you drag and drop quickly on desktop for a file that is not yet downloaded, native os operation does nothing
5. This makes it practically useless

**Any Suggestions ?**

Comment: Hi, I know it's old, but did you solve it?

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer!